# When to use \ in grep search string

Tags: linux, command-line, search, grep, string

I have file content similar to:

```
A+B
C+D
A+B
```

These are strings. I want to search for the occurrence of `A+B`. So I write the command as: `grep 'A+B' test.txt`. However, if I write `grep 'A\+B' test.txt` I do not get any results? 
While if instead of `+` the string contains `.`, if I add `\` or nor add, I get the search results. I do not understand:

1) When should I add `\` and when I should not.

2) Why I did not get any results when I added it in `+` while I got results when I added it in `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what flavor of `grep` you use but it's possible you
use `GNU grep`.  By default `grep` uses `Basic Regular Expressions`,
and as it's explained in `man grep`:

> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (,
>   and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed
>   versions \?, +, {, \|, (, and ).

Notice that if you used `-E` you would switch to `Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)` and would have to use `\+` because by in default in
`ERE` and many other regular expressions syntaxes `+` stands for `one or more of the preceding character`:

```
$ grep -E 'A\+B' test.txt
A+B
A+B
```

So, to answer your questions:

1. You should use `\` when you want to search for literal character.
2. In `BRE` a single dot stands for `any character` just like in `ERE`.

Answer (score 0):

In `egrep` (or `grep -E`) extended regular expressions are enabled. These include:

```
+ - match one or more instances of the previous match pattern.
```

These can be used in basic `grep` with a preceding back-slash, which doesn't have its usual meaning of making literal, but invokes the `egrep` function.

So the following are equivalent:-

```
egrep 'A+B'
grep 'A\+B'
```

In both cases the match is for one or more `A`s followed immediately by `B`.

Because in `egrep` there is a special meaning for '+', it must be escaped to match literally, so the following are also equivalent:

```
egrep 'A\+B'
grep 'A+B'
```

These will both match `A+B`, since a literal '+' is sought in both cases.

Other `egrep` functions that can be used by escaping in `grep` include `\|` for alternative match strings and `\{M,N\}`, where M and N are numbers representing the minimum and maximum of repetitions on a match pattern. These are not escaped in `egrep`.